# data splitting in a dataframe with streaming data

Tags: python, pandas

have the following code for retrieving the stock name and its ltp.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=None)

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global df
    for sc in ticks:
        token=sc['instrument_token']
        name=trd_portfolio[token]['name']
        ltp=sc['last_price']
        df=df.append([name,ltp],ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

However, both the appended items, ie. name and ltp are getting extracted in the same column due to which am unable to manipulate the data further. Same of the output is as below

```
              0
0     BANKBARODA
1          39.05
2     NATCOPHARM
3         574.55
4     AUROPHARMA
         ...
4249      194.15
4250     FRETAIL
4251        80.9
4252    HDFCLIFE
4253      517.95

[4254 rows x 1 columns]
```

please suggest a way so that i can have the name and ltp in two different columns for further working.

Answer (score 0):

Use double braces:

```
df = df.append([[name, ltp]], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# creating a new dataframe with name and ltp values
# however, since the requirement is to have these within individual 
# columns and not rows, using transpose (T) to address it
df1 = pd.DataFrame([name,ltp]).T

# explicitly adding column names to the temp dataframe and the same will repeat
# everytime a new temp dataframe is formed. This will ensure that the new values
# get appended to the correct columns in the aggregated version
df1.columns = ['name', 'ltp']

# append the temp dataframe to the aggregated version to be published as final
df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. for better presentation can be name the column as name and ltp rather than index nos. of 0 & 1

Comment: Thank you so much. because its a streaming data within a for loop am unable to stop the data for further manipulation like sort, buy sell etc. is there a way to have the subseqent processes done simultaneously. I had ready about async function but do not know how it can be done. if possible please guide.

Comment: That would depend on what exactly you want to do with data. Also IIUC, you cannot perform aggregate operations on streaming data.

Comment: want to perform groupby, count  etc to decide which name to buy or sell. my issue is i am not sure of how to do both the streaming and other operations on the dataframe concurrently.

Comment: As I mentioned, you won't be able to do groupby, count etc with accuracy on streaming data. May be you can ask the question as a separate one or uodate this one with sample input data and expected output and someone might be able to answer.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @SherylHohman. Agreed. Will try to add explanation and update the answer.